# What is a collective mode?

Tags: condensed-matter, field-theory, definition

I am looking for:

1. a general definition of collective mode appearing often in condensed matter.
2. concrete examples of collective modes.

I have some ideas in my mind but I wish I could compare it with a clear text-book-like description.

Comment: It might be helpful for you to outline what the ideas you have in your mind are, so that people know what level to pitch their answers at

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple examples of collective modes: the normal modes of a mass-spring chain. This is pretty close to phonon modes in a solid state system. But the same principle applies to any other situation where many parts of a system are coupled and oscillate at the same frequency.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WE-HB8DBFU4